# you must mark my words?

Tags: riddle, word

I am a 6 letter word!

**Remove the last two from me, you just did this to me.**

Death penalty awaits you if you take key letters from me, I mean, that is my stand.

**I hope no one dares to attack my body as it is already censored, I remain the same after it happens. And it may sound puzzling to you.**

Find me please :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you...

> EDITED

Remove the last two from me, you just did this to me.

> EDITED --> EDIT (I did just edit the word)

Death penalty awaits you if you take key letters from me, I mean, that is my stand.

> EDITED - [TED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Key) --> DIE

I hope no one dares to attack my body as it is already censored, I remain the same after it happens. And it may sound puzzling to you.

> EDITED - ED = DITE* = EDIT (censor)

Comment: There you go! Nice work and congratz! Some more rationale: "Key words, i mean ,that is my stand " implies letters in prime number position , which is DIE.    Also, I remains the same after it happens. edITed  . It is ED before and after IT.

Comment: @JyotishRobin If this is correct, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is

> CHANGE

As

> remove last two letters, you changed it and
>  Remove C, E to get HANG (a kind of death penalty)

and

> Change remained change after a change, in a way !

Comment: That is a brilliant attempt. But not the answer what i thought of. As a reminder, the question says if you take key letters, it is not "if you remove".

Answer (score 1):

Probably

> Parent

Trimming the last 2

> Pare - means to trim

Key letters that warrants Death Penalty (as per your stand)

> R A P E

Could not decode the last clue.

Comment: Good try! The last clue is very powerful as it could even land you in the answer directly, with some guessing attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Another guess

> FILMED

Removing last 2 letters

> FILM - did film whatever it was filmed

Key Letters taken from you that warrants a Death Penalty

> L I F E

Censored

> FILMED content being censored

Comment: I think you are neglecting the clue I remain the same after it happens.